# How to iterate map to avoid NPE?

Tags: java, dictionary, nullpointerexception

I am generating an URL basis on the hostname being passed to my below method.

`UserId` and `ClientId` will be passed always but the `DataMap` will be empty sometimes. Here DataMap is of `String` and `String`.

My below code is throwing `NullPointerException` if the `keys.getDataMap()` is empty.

```
private String generateURL(final String hostIPAdress) {
    StringBuffer url = new StringBuffer();
    url.append("http://" + hostIPAdress + ":8080/user?userid=" + keys.getUserId() + "&client_id="
        + keys.getClientId());

    // this line throw NPE
    Set<Entry<String, String>> params = keys.getDataMap().entrySet();

    for (Entry<String, String> e : params) {
        url.append("&" + e.getKey());
        url.append("=" + e.getValue());
    }

    return url.toString();
}
```

If only `UserId` and `ClientId` is passed and `DataMap` is empty then I will make URL like this -

```
hostname:8080/user?userid=1234567&client_id=20
```

But in the above case, it is throwing NPE as the map is empty. How do I fix this problem?

And if the map data is being passed, then I will make url like this -

```
hostname:8080/user?userid=1234567&client_id=20&attribute=testing
```

Here `attribute` is key of the map and `testing` is the value of that key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just check if your map is `null` or not:

```
final Map dataMap = keys.getDataMap();
if (dataMap != null)
{
    Set<Entry<String, String>> params = dataMap.entrySet();
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Add a fence:

```
Map dataMap= keys.getDataMap();
if (dataMap != null)
{
    Set<Entry<String, String>> params = dataMap.entrySet();
    // ...
}
```

Make sure you include appropriate logic within the braces, and return some suitable default value from the function if `getDataMap()` returns null.

Answer (score 1):

It throws an NPE not because it's empty, it's null. A trivial null check should do.
Consider:

```
private String generateURL( final String hostIPAdress ) {
    StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder();
    url.append( "http://" ).append( hostIPAdress )
        .append( ":8080/user?userid=" ).append( keys.getUserId() )
        .append( "&client_id=" ).append( keys.getClientId() );

    if( keys.getDataMap() == null ) {
        return url.toString();
    }

    for( Entry< String, String > e : keys.getDataMap().entrySet() ) {
        url.append( '&' ).append( e.getKey() ).append( '=' ).append( e.getValue() );
    }

    return url.toString();
}
```

Comment: You made the same mistake in the original comment you posted.  It's not `I`, it's `It`.